# How to capture traffic from an entire website (including external servers) using tcpdump

Tags: networking, tcpdump, packet

I was wondering if its possible to capture all network traffic coming from a single website using `tcpdump`. I am interested in capturing the sizes of all incoming and outgoing packets from and to a certain website. However, something like `tcpdump -n host washingtonpost.com` will only (I tried this on the terminal) give the traffic coming from `washingtonpost`'s directly resolved servers and not for example all the external `CDNs`, or the `Advertising Servers` et cetera. Since I do not know the `IP addresses` or `hostnames` of these servers beforehand, I cannot create a filter of somekind. Does anyone know of a way I could do this or whether this is indeed possible?

Thanks.

Comment: @steve I am doing this on the client side, that is just with my web browser, but thats a solution on the server end, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. Why ? Communication-Protocol http/https is the key here. tcpdump is "only" designated to capture lower level protocol. There is no filter on tcpdump to analyze traffic in-flight and do a expansion on the filter. But this would be necessary to meat your requirements.

You could use a Web-Proxy Cache or some other "in the middle" software. 
Also it is easy to impediment using Perl or Python scripts if HTTP would be the target. A little more work and in special with certificates in case of HTTPS.

```
+-------------+     +------------+     +------------+
| web-Browser |-----| HTTP/HTTPS |-----| HTTP/HTTPS |
+-------------+     | Proxy      |     | Server     |
                    +------------+     +------------+
```

You can use iptables on Linux do redirect all traffice to target port 80/443 to the web-proxy/"man in the middle"-program/script or use the proxy-parameter on you web-browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, basically, I have to create my own `MITM proxy`, redirect all the traffic there, and that way capture all the requests, but that would be on the `HTTP` layer, no? And I need `packet` sizes on the `IP` layer. Is that possible through this? (I have never used `iptables` before)

Comment: Yes right - your focus should be on HTTP/HTTPS protocol. You don't have to care about packet size on IP layer to meet your requirements. You can use "sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.217.16.163:80" to redirect all outgoing traffic to port 80 - in this example to "goolge.de"

Comment: But how will I obtain the packet sizes in that case?

Comment: "packet size" should be equal to the size of the request and response buffers. so in case of a web-proxy watch the access-log file. it will provide the length of the data. if you use a script/program just use the size information of the socket operation.